# Checking the validity of Resource Records in DNS Zones

Tags: domain-name-system, perl, dns-zone, nsd

I am using perl to do some DNS manipulation tasks.

I am using [NSD](https://nlnetlabs.nl/projects/nsd/about/) as my DNS server.

I want to figure out what the best way is to check whether the names of all Resource Records in a DNS zone file are valid.

There seem to be a couple of possibilities (that I can think of) to do the checking:

1. nsd-checkzone
2. An already made Perl module https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Validate::Domain
3. Do the checking manually in perl by knowing all the RFCs describing what is a valid name and what is not.

The main problem, in my opinion, arises when special names of Resource Records come into question.

For example: I have seen online that there is a possibility to use a * as a name of a Resource Record:

```
*                IN A      192.168.150.144
```

This supposedly means return this record if no other record matches.

I have also seen some "special" names of Resource Records (in reverse DNS zones) like in [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2317) RFC:

```
   192/26          NS      ns.C.domain.
   192/26          NS      some.other.third.name.server.
   0/25            NS      ns.A.domain.
   0/25            NS      some.other.name.server.
```

I also have an additional question:

- Where can I see all these special names of Resource Records allowed in Forward and Reverse DNS zones and their meaning? (because I want to know them all :) )

Answer (score 1):

IMHO zone files are a PITA to manipulate as text files...

For starters:

each  RR **should look like** `name ttl record_class record_type record_data` BUT :

- `name` can be omitted, and then the record inherits the field from the previous record.
- `ttl` can be omitted and will become the value of `$TTL`
- `record_class` is often also omitted because hardly anyone uses anything but the default `IN`

And that is only the start of your problems.

---

Especially if your zones were maintained by hand it can be difficult to distinguish shorthand from typo's and really crafty tricks of the trade, which can make entries (even more) context dependant. Your parsing difficulties can be aggravated even more when for instance $-directives come into play.

Then there is of course also the difference between a zone file with a **valid syntax** as confirmed with the `nsd-checkzone` or `named-checkzone`  and resource records that are semantically valid and **work as intended**.

A fairly typical example is a CNAME record in the example.com zone

```
www IN CNAME www.example.net
```

which is valid, but since there is no trailing dot on `www.example.net` that is not a FQDN and zone file shorthand. The value of $ORIGIN will be appended and by default that becomes:

```
www IN CNAME www.example.net.example.com.
```

That is not *always* the case though.
Rather than using an implicit value of $ORIGIN, or following convention and explicitly setting $ORIGIN to the name of the zone, people sometimes explicitly [define $ORIGIN to only a `.` dot](https://serverfault.com/q/879913/37681).

Again the example of  a CNAME record in the example.com zone

```
$ORIGIN .

www IN CNAME www.example.net
```

Then when value of $ORIGIN will be appended that becomes:

```
www IN CNAME www.example.net.
```

[This Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/609985/37681) is an example of where the location of the MX record resulted in valid syntax but broken e-mail.

[This answer of mine](https://serverfault.com/a/819242/37681) is an example of a bad idea, but valid syntax where the context of a Resource Record depends on the exact position within a zone file and the effect of shorthand will change due to repeated use/abuse of the $ORIGIN $-directive.

Comment: Why can't I find a full list on what is allowed as a symbol and what not? Are glob expressions allowed, are regular expressions allowed, what is allowed? I guess I need to e-mail NSD specifically for this issue because a valid zone  may be different for different authoritative nameserver software. Or, go through the source code to see what they missed. Non-working records are not a big concern in my opinion since they can be corrected if they do not work. From this discussion I came to the conclusion that as long as NSD doesn't crash, I'm okay with it.

Comment: Probably because the only people who need such a list are the ones who like you need to write zone file parsers, like https://nlnetlabs.nl/documentation/nsd/grammar-for-dns-zone-files/ refers you back to the code. Usually wikipedia is always good for lists though: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types and of interest may be: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Domain_name_syntax

Comment: Okay, thank you for taking the time to answer. I really appreciate it. I will take a look at the links you gave me. Sometimes I get really annoyed when something isn't documented well. Maybe I should do something about it instead of whining.