# Two nameserver domains that refer to each other causing issues

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, dns-hosting

I have a VPS which hosts multiple domains including (modified for privacy):

```
mydomain.co.uk
mydomain.uk
```

I have registered name server GLUE (verified) for the following - all use the same IP address:

```
ns1.mydomain.co.uk
ns2.mydomain.co.uk
ns1.mydomain.uk
ns2.mydomain.uk
```

Each of the 2 domains is set to use all 4 nameservers.

All of the other hosted domains use 2 nameservers; either ns1 and ns2.mydomain.uk, or ns1 and ns2.mydomain.co.uk - also all at the same IP.

All domains work fine (the server up web services and send/receive mail appropriately).

When I use DNS checking services such as viewdns.info or intodns.com, there are errors on mydomain.co.uk, mydomain.uk AND to varying degrees all of the hosted domains which use either pair. The hosted domains are .co.uk, .com, .uk.com, and org.

Errors seen are:

**IntoDNS**

> ERROR: Some of your DNS servers do not have A records at all. I could not find any A records for the following DNS servers

> WARNING: One or more of your nameservers did not return any of your NS records.
> NS records got from your nameservers listed at the parent NS are:

> Oups! I could not get any nameservers from your nameservers (the ones listed at the parent server). Please verify that they are not lame nameservers and are configured properly.

**ViewDNS**

> Oops! Your local nameservers don't return IP addresses (glue) along with your NS records! This isn't a fatal error but means an extra lookup needs to be performed increasing the load time to your site. You can fix this by adding A records for each of the nameservers listed above.

I wonder if the problem is the self-referential nature of the configuration? Or should that be absolutely fine?

The DNS zone for mydomain.co.uk includes (where xxx is my server IP address):

```
mydomain.co.uk. A xxx
ns1.mydomain.co.uk. A xxx
ns2.mydomain.co.uk. A xxx
mydomain.co.uk. NS ns1.mydomain.co.uk
mydomain.co.uk. NS ns2.mydomain.co.uk
mydomain.co.uk. NS ns1.mydomain.uk
mydomain.co.uk. NS ns2.mydomain.uk
```

Similarly the DNS zone for mydomain.uk includes records:

```
mydomain.uk. A xxx
ns1.mydomain.uk. A xxx
ns2.mydomain.uk. A xxx
mydomain.uk. NS ns1.mydomain.co.uk
mydomain.uk. NS ns2.mydomain.co.uk
mydomain.uk. NS ns1.mydomain.uk
mydomain.uk. NS ns2.mydomain.uk
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: "I wonder if the problem is the self-referential nature of the configuration?" - self reference is a problem -> https://ns1.com/blog/glue-records-and-dedicated-dns

Comment: It might be an issue with your obfuscation but your zone file appear to be full of FQDN’s that are missing the trailing dot `.` - And then they are not considered a FQDN and bind will treat them as short-hand. And `mydomain.uk` gets interpreted as  `mydomain.uk.mydomain.uk.`      https://serverfault.com/a/939179/37681 For some context

Comment: I've added . at the end of each record in the question above. The dots are present in the actual records already.

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your child name-server under your domain registry.
check out this link for details about the child namserver:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50386272/what-is-child-nameserver-and-what-is-use-of-it

Comment: I already did this, yes.